# Disappearing the data from recyclerview for some time when populating it with data from firebase

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm developing a basic chat application using firebase. I'm able to store and retrieve data/messages from firebase! But when I scroll through the chat(Recyclerview) some of the messages doesn't show up/disappears for a while.

Something like this:
[image: Losing chat messages]

When I go back to the userlist_activity, and then again come to the chat_activity it shows all the messages. But if I scroll again through the chat, some messages disappers untill I go back and come again. I've checked through my firebase DB many times to see if I'm missing those messages. But no, all messages are there in the DB. But still disappering from chat window!

Here's my MainActivity/ChatAcitivty:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private static final String TAG = "MainActivity";

public static final String ANONYMOUS = "anonymous";
public static final int DEFAULT_MSG_LENGTH_LIMIT = 1000;
private static final int RC_SIGN_IN = 1;

private RecyclerView mMessageRecyclerView;
private MessageAdapter mMessageAdapter;
private ProgressBar mProgressBar;
private ImageButton mPhotoPickerButton;
private EditText mMessageEditText;
private Button mSendButton;

private String mUsername;
private String mUserId;
private String friendUserID;
private ArrayList<ChatMessage> friendlyMessages;
private ArrayList<ChatMessage> selectedItems = new ArrayList<>();
private boolean multiSelect = false;
private int mPosition;

private FirebaseDatabase mFirebaseDatabase;     //Entry Point to the database
private DatabaseReference mMessageDatabaseReference;   //Reference to the specific part of the database.
private ChildEventListener mChildEventListener;
private FirebaseAuth mFirebaseAuth;
private FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener mAuthStateListener;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mUsername = ANONYMOUS;
    mFirebaseDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    mFirebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

    friendUserID = getIntent().getStringExtra("clickedUserID");
    setTitle(getIntent().getStringExtra("clickedUsername"));
    SendBird.setFriendUserID(friendUserID);

    mMessageDatabaseReference = mFirebaseDatabase.getReference().child("message");
    mMessageDatabaseReference.keepSynced(true);

    // Initialize references to views
    mProgressBar = findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
    mMessageRecyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recycler_view_message);
    mPhotoPickerButton = findViewById(R.id.photoPickerButton);
    mMessageEditText = findViewById(R.id.messageEditText);
    mSendButton = findViewById(R.id.sendButton);

    // Initialize message RecyclerView and its adapter
    friendlyMessages = new ArrayList<>();
    mMessageAdapter = new MessageAdapter(friendlyMessages, this);
    mMessageRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
    mMessageRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
    mMessageRecyclerView.setAdapter(mMessageAdapter);

    // Initialize progress bar
    mProgressBar.setVisibility(ProgressBar.INVISIBLE);

    // ImagePickerButton shows an image picker to upload a image for a message
    mPhotoPickerButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            // TODO: Fire an intent to show an image picker
        }
    });

    mMessageEditText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {
            if (charSequence.toString().trim().length() > 0) {
                mSendButton.setEnabled(true);
            } else {
                mSendButton.setEnabled(false);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {
        }
    });
    mMessageEditText.setFilters(new InputFilter[]{new InputFilter.LengthFilter(DEFAULT_MSG_LENGTH_LIMIT)});

    mSendButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            ChatMessage chatMessage = new ChatMessage(mUsername, null, mMessageEditText.getText().toString(),
                    System.currentTimeMillis(), mUserId, friendUserID);
            mMessageDatabaseReference.push().setValue(chatMessage);
            // Clear input box
            mMessageEditText.setText("");
        }
    });

    mAuthStateListener = new FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAuthStateChanged(@NonNull FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth) {

            FirebaseUser user = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();
            if (user != null) {
                onSignedInInitialize(user.getDisplayName(), user.getUid());
            } else {
                onSignedOutCleanup();
            }
        }
    };
}

private void onSignedOutCleanup() {
    mUsername = ANONYMOUS;
    clear();
    detachDatabaseReadListener();
}

private void onSignedInInitialize(String userName, String userId) {
    mUsername = userName;
    mUserId = userId;
    attachDatabaseReadListener();
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.main_menu, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.sign_out_menu:
            AuthUI.getInstance().signOut(this);
            return true;

        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (requestCode == RC_SIGN_IN) {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Signed in!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } else if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Sign in canceled!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            finish();
        }
    }
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    mFirebaseAuth.addAuthStateListener(mAuthStateListener);

    attachDatabaseReadListener();
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    if (mAuthStateListener != null) {
        mFirebaseAuth.removeAuthStateListener(mAuthStateListener);
    }
    detachDatabaseReadListener();
    clear();
}

private void attachDatabaseReadListener() {
    if (mChildEventListener == null) {
        mChildEventListener = new ChildEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
                ChatMessage chatMessage = dataSnapshot.getValue(ChatMessage.class);
                friendlyMessages.add(chatMessage);
              //mMessageAdapter.notifyItemInserted(friendlyMessages.size() - 1);
                mMessageAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                mMessageRecyclerView.smoothScrollToPosition(friendlyMessages.size() - 1);
            }

            @Override
            public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
            }
        };
        mMessageDatabaseReference.addChildEventListener(mChildEventListener);
    }
}

private void detachDatabaseReadListener() {
    if (mChildEventListener != null) {
        mMessageDatabaseReference.removeEventListener(mChildEventListener);
        mChildEventListener = null;
    }
}

public void clear() {
    int size = this.friendlyMessages.size();
    friendlyMessages.clear();
    mMessageAdapter.notifyItemRangeRemoved(0, size);
   }
}
```

Here's my MessageAdapter:

```
public class MessageAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter {

private static final int VIEW_TYPE_MESSAGE_SENT = 1;
private static final int VIEW_TYPE_MESSAGE_RECEIVED = 2;

private ArrayList<ChatMessage> chatList;
private Context mContext;


public MessageAdapter(ArrayList<ChatMessage> chatList, Context mContext) {
    this.chatList = chatList;
    this.mContext = mContext;
}

@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {
    ChatMessage chatMessage = chatList.get(position);

    if (chatMessage.getUserId().equals(SendBird.getCurrnetUserId())) {
        // If the current user is the sender of the message
        Log.d("Adapter", "type message sent");
        return VIEW_TYPE_MESSAGE_SENT;
    } else {
        // If some other user sent the message
        return VIEW_TYPE_MESSAGE_RECEIVED;
    }

}

@Override
public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view;
    if (viewType == VIEW_TYPE_MESSAGE_SENT) {
        view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.item_message_sent, parent, false);
        Log.d("Adapter", "create message sent");
        return new SentMessageHolder(view);
    } else if (viewType == VIEW_TYPE_MESSAGE_RECEIVED) {
        view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.item_message_received, parent, false);
        return new ReceivedMessageHolder(view);
    }

    return null;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    ChatMessage message = chatList.get(position);

    switch (holder.getItemViewType()) {
        case VIEW_TYPE_MESSAGE_SENT:
            ((SentMessageHolder) holder).bind(message);
            Log.d("Adapter", "bind message sent");
            break;
        case VIEW_TYPE_MESSAGE_RECEIVED:
            ((ReceivedMessageHolder) holder).bind(message);
    }
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return chatList.size();
}

private class SentMessageHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    TextView messageTextView;
    TextView authorTextView;
    TextView mTimeTextView;
    ImageView photoImageView;

    public SentMessageHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        messageTextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.messageTextView);
        authorTextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.nameTextView);
        photoImageView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.photoImageView);
        mTimeTextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.timeTextView);
    }

    void bind(ChatMessage message) {
        String to = message.getzFriendUserId();

        if (to.equals(SendBird.getFriendUserID())) {
            messageTextView.setText(message.getText());
            authorTextView.setText("You");
            // Format the stored timestamp into a readable String using method.
            mTimeTextView.setText(Utils.formatDateTime(message.getTime()));
        } else {
            itemView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }

    }
}

private class ReceivedMessageHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    TextView messageTextView;
    TextView authorTextView;
    TextView mTimeTextView;
    ImageView photoImageView;

    ReceivedMessageHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        messageTextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.messageTextView);
        authorTextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.nameTextView);
        photoImageView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.photoImageView);
        mTimeTextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.timeTextView);
    }

    void bind(ChatMessage message) {
        String friendUserId = message.getzFriendUserId();
        String sendId = message.getUserId();
        if (friendUserId.equals(SendBird.getCurrnetUserId()) && SendBird.getFriendUserID().equals(sendId)) {
            messageTextView.setText(message.getText());
            authorTextView.setText(message.getName());
            // Format the stored timestamp into a readable String using method.
            mTimeTextView.setText(Utils.formatDateTime(message.getTime()));
        } else {
            itemView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
    }
  }

}
```

I think it's something related to firebase syncing, but I'm not sure exactly what's causing this problem. Any suggestions/answers would be very helpful!

**Update**

item_message_received.xml

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
android:background="@drawable/rounded_rectangle_white"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/messageTextView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="8dp"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    tools:text="Message" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/nameTextView"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/timeTextView"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/messageTextView"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/messageTextView"
    tools:text="Name" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/timeTextView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/messageTextView"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/messageTextView"
    tools:text="2:35PM" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/photoImageView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"/>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

item_message_sent.xml:

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
android:background="#E0E0E0">

<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/constraint2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
    android:background="@drawable/rounded_rectangle_white"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/messageTextView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/constraint2"
        tools:text="Message" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/nameTextView"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/constraint2"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/timeTextView"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/messageTextView"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/messageTextView"
        tools:text="Name" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/timeTextView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/constraint2"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/messageTextView"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/messageTextView"
        tools:text="2:35PM" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/photoImageView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: As I understad you have separate layouts for sent\receive states, could it be that the gap is result of received layout? Please, share some layouts code.

Comment: I don't think so, because it's happening with the sent messages too, and as I said I can see messages in the firebase server/database, and also when I come to the chat activity again!!
But I'll share my layout code anyway.. :)